# display just one productFlavors when generate signed apk

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

In my gradle.bluid, i have two productFlavors, so i like

```
    productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationId "aareon.fr.myapplication"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.dev
        buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png"'
    }

    prod {
        applicationId "aareon.fr.myapplication"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.prod
        buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/630285593268752384/iD1MkFQ0.png"'
    }
}
```

So when i want to generate a signed `APK` i want to `diplay` one among the 2 `productFlavors` for exemple if i want prod :

productFlavors : prod

[image]

or if i want dev :

productFlavors : dev

[image: image2]

but the problem is all the time i have two productFlavors like this :

[image: image3]

this my Build.gradle :

```
    signingConfigs {

    dev {
        storeFile file("C:\\Users\\mzarroug\\Desktop\\keystoreFacke\\debug.keystore.jks")
        storePassword "xxxxxxx"
        keyAlias "xxxxxxx"
        keyPassword "xxxxxxxx"
    }
    prod {
        storeFile file("C:\\Users\\mzarroug\\Desktop\\keystoreFacke\\prod.keystore.jks")
        storePassword "xxxxxxx"
        keyAlias "xxxxxxx"
        keyPassword "xxxxxxx"
    }
}

productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationId "aareon.fr.myapplication"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.dev
        buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png"'
    }

    prod {
        applicationId "aareon.fr.myapplication"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.prod
        buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/630285593268752384/iD1MkFQ0.png"'
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.prod
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField("boolean", "isDebug", "false")
    }
    debug{
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.dev
        buildConfigField("boolean","isDebug","true")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sudheesh R do you have a solution ??

Comment: What is the issue in having the default behaviour, does it cause some issue to you ?

Comment: my problem is i want to display just one of productFlavors if i need dev I show dev productFlavors and THE SAME for productFlavors prod at generate Signed APK

Comment: Ok, if you insist, then you can comment the code for product flavor (which you do not want) in build.gradle.

Comment: it's not exactly that,

i want when i choose debug.keystore i display productFlavors dev and when i choose prod.keystore  i display productFlavors prod